# MVC4 : Interface object in Model

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm quite new about MVC. I have the following Model classes:

```
public class Store
{   
  public PriceList PriceListInfo { get; set; }
  public IStore storeData;
}    

public class PriceList
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string codice { get; set; }
}    

public interface IStore
{
 [...]
}    

public class Silo2Store : IStore
{
  public int S2 { get; set; }
  public int S3 { get; set; }
}
```

And i want use this model in my view:

```
@model Store

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => ((Silo2Store)Model.storeData).S3)
```

The corresponding Controller method is:

```
public ActionResult Customer()
{
    using (Store t = (Store)Session["Store"])
    {
        if (t.PriceListInfo == null)
        {
            t.PriceListInfo = new PriceList();
        }
        t.PriceListInfo.codice = "XXX";
        return View(t);
    }
}
```

And I'd like to retrieve the model in my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Customer(Store modelStore)
{
    var test = ((Silo2Store)Model.storeData).S3;
}
```

but `Model.storeData` attribute isn't initialized in my view, it's `null`. Then, I can't  retrieve the value in my controller.

Should I change my model in anyway?

Comment: Can you show us the code of your GET controller method?

Comment: '  public ActionResult Customer()
        {

            using (Store t = (Store)Session["Store"])
            {         

                    if (t.PriceListInfo == null)
                    {
                        t.PriceListInfo = new PriceList();
                    }
                    t.PriceListInfo.codice = "XXX";



                    return View(t);

            }
        }'

Comment: ..When I check my Model in the view (in debug mode), the object "storeData" isn't null. It's NULL in controller side.

Comment: I think you'll have to define your own model binder for `IStore`. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) may be helpful as a starting point...

Comment: YES!....I've created my model binder. It seems to work now. Tnx.

Comment: Great! I've converted my comment to an answer so that you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your own model binder for `IStore`.

Taken from [this article on MSDN Magazine about MVC Model Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx):

> For example, even though the Microsoft .NET Framework provides excellent support for object-oriented principles, the DefaultModelBinder offers no support for binding to abstract base classes and interfaces.