# .NET 5.0 Razor - Interface object and model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, model-binding

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5.0 with Razor Pages.

I've much more complex object but for describing my problem I've make it as simple as possible. Let's assume that our object with interface is something like below:

```
Invoice.cs:
public class Invoice
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IRule Rules { get; set; }
}

SimpleRule.cs:
public class SimpleRule : IRule
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

IndexModel.cshtml:
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Invoice Details { get; set; }

    (...)
}
```

After submitting form property 'Name' is set, but unfortunately 'Rules' is null. It works when I change IRule to SimpleRule, but I have to put there interface with different models. As far as I read DefaultModelBinder does not support interfaces, I have to write my own but... how?

There was common problem
[MVC4 : Interface object in Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266881/mvc4-interface-object-in-model) but it was 9 years ago.
Also I've tired something like here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/february/asp-net-mvc-the-features-and-foibles-of-asp-net-mvc-model-binding without any success.

Does anyone have any solution or tips how to write my own modelbinder with interfaces?

Comment: Maybe you can try custom [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: MVC binding needs to know how to map an incoming name like `"Details.Rules."` to a single type at compile time. I've approached this problem by creating a wrapping class, with a property for each potential type, (eg `public SimpleRule Simple => Rules as SimpleRule;`) and a custom model binder to construct the correct type from a discriminator value. Then you can bind `Details.Simple.Value` vs `Details.Complex.Something`.